# 2 C++ classes with same functionality but different variable names - which pattern to use?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance, design-patterns

I have 2 C++ classes which have the same variable types and need to perform exactly the same operations on these variables. However, the variable and function names of these 2 classes are different as they mean different things in their respective classes.

How can I achieve this without code duplication? Does inheritance or templates help here?

Here's a stripped down example.

```
class A
{
    private:
       float m;
       float n;

    public:
       float foo() {return m + n};
};

class B
{
    private:
       float p;
       float q;

    public:
       float bar() {return p + q};
};
```

In my case, the operations and variables are more complicated than the above toy example. The only difference between the 2 classes are the variable and function names. The rest is identical. How can I refactor this in C++?

Comment: Well, you should all yourself why they are separate in the first place. Why not just use one class in both situations? (I think most other solutions might add unnecessary complexity)

Comment: *How can I achieve this without code duplication?* -- There is no issue with code duplication.  If the types mean different things, it is just a coincidence that the classes have the same layout.  What if my class with 20 members is called `Car`, and another that by chance has the same 20 members, but it is `Toaster`?.  BTW, if you look at a real-world program, that program can have numerous "two member" classes, all meaning different things.

Comment: It would be helpfull if we know what those classes are.

Comment: What about using a `std::pair<float,float>` as generalization (resp `class Base<T> { std::pair<T,T> y;  public: T baz() { return y.first + y.second; }};` )?

Comment: Just to echo @PaulMcKenzie, there's no issue with having two different types with the same layout, if they are used to represent different things and are used in different situations. If you REALLY want to only have one type (let's say it's called `MySingleType`), you can do `typedef MySingleType NameOne;` and `typedef MySingleType NameTwo;` to create aliases, then you can use `NameOne` and `NameTwo` as if they were their own types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to deal with this.

1. Just use one class. If the functionality is the same and you are just changing names, then why do you need more than one class.

   - PROS: minimize code duplication
   - CONS: if these are for two different applications, you are violating the single responsibility principle
2. Create a base class with all the functions and then another for each case with the correct names.

   - PROS: minimize code duplication
   - CONS: may not be related by other than chance
3. Create a single class and `typedef` to create another name.

   - PROS: minimize code duplication
   - CONS: only the name of the 'class' is changed, not the method calls
4. Leave it as two classes

   - PROS: each class is responsible for it's own non-related operations and acts independently of the other
   - CONS: possible code duplication

In general, without knowing the specifics of the classes, I would say that the best approach is to leave both classes as they are. If they are doing different things, and just happen to both have similar methods, that is chance and doesn't merit sacrificing readability and the single responsibility principle.
If they are related, then consider if it would follow an inherited relationship. If not, again, leave them as two classes.

Answer (score 1):

Two reasonably-complex functions that are the same except for which variables are used? Sounds like a simple case where the commonality could be extracted into a separate function, which takes arguments for the things that differ. For example:

```
float DoComplicatedThing(float a, float b)
{
    // whatever the complicated thing is
    // ...

    // but staying with your example it's just:
    return a + b;
}

class A
{
    private:
       float m;
       float n;

    public:
       float foo() { return DoComplicatedThing(m, n) };
};

class B
{
    private:
       float p;
       float q;

    public:
       float bar() { return DoComplicatedThing(p, q) };
};
```

If there's a good reason to have `A` and `B` derive from a common base class, then `DoComplicatedThing` could potentially be a static function from that base class. Otherwise it could just be a standalone function without a class (as in my example).